# check current page URL with Nightmare

Tags: node.js, typescript, nightmare

I am writing an automated test with Nightmare.js and typescript. The first objective of this test is to test I've landed at the correct page.

I have done some research, but have not found anything useful to me.

Here is my code:

```
 import * as Nightmare from "nightmare";

 describe("Login Page", function() {   this.timeout("30s");

   let nightmare = null;   beforeEach(() => {


 nightmare = new Nightmare({ show: true });   });

   describe("give correct details", () => {
     it("should log-in, check for current page url", done => {
       nightmare
         .goto(www.example.com/log-in)
         .wait(5000)
         .type("input[type='email']", "username")
         .type("input[type='password']", "password")
         .click(".submit")
         .wait(3000)
         SOMETHING THAT SHOULD CHECK URL HERE
         .end()
         .then(result => {
           done();
         })
         .catch(done);
     });   
}); 
});
```

Where it says "SOMETHING THAT SHOULD CHECK URL HERE" I would like something to put the current url into a variable for later reference then console.log it. All answers are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways to do it. I'll be using the simplest solution for this.

```
let SOMEGLOBALVAR; // so we can access it later
// Codes in between ...
.click(".submit")
.wait(3000)
.url() // <-- use the built in url
.end()
.then(url => {
  SOMEGLOBALVAR = url; // set it to a global variable if you want
  done();
})
```

You can change it however you want.

Note: Global vars are considered bad practice. The above snippet is just for illustrating the `.url` function.

Comment: Thanks for that, the issue I had with my previous attempts was I kept trying to pass the function before .end()